# What happens when I try to store more 8019 bytes in a SQL Server table row?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I read -

total fixed and variable length data are still limited to 8019 bytes total

But my data can possibly be more than this. What happens if it's more. Does it still store the data correctly?

Also can someone tell me how I can store for example over 4000 bytes of text data in a column. Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks. I will use that next time. I didn't even know it existed.

Comment: @Gemma you must have read about data types and their sizes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data exceeding the total of 8060 bytes will be pushed over to an 'overflow page', increasing the amount of pages required to be read from the buffer pool.

Answer (score 4):

From [Row-Overflow Data Exceeding 8 KB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) :

> A table can contain a maximum of 8,060 bytes per row. In SQL Server
>   2008, this restriction is relaxed for tables that contain varchar,
>   nvarchar, varbinary, sql_variant, or CLR user-defined type columns.
>   The length of each one of these columns must still fall within the
>   limit of 8,000 bytes; however, their combined widths can exceed the
>   8,060-byte limit

That means it's really hard to hit the 8kb limit.  You could script it:

```
if object_id('YourTable') is not null
    drop table YourTable
go
create table YourTable (id int identity);
declare @i int = 1
declare @sql varchar(max)
while @i < 800
    begin
    set @sql =  'alter table YourTable add col' + cast(@i as varchar(24)) + 
        ' decimal(38);'
    exec (@sql)
    set @i = @i + 1
    end
```

This will show you the error message:

> Msg 1701, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Creating or altering table
>   'YourTable' failed because the minimum row size would be 8076,
>   including 65 bytes of internal overhead. This exceeds the maximum
>   allowable table row size of 8060 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `varchar(max)`, `nvarchar(max)` datatypes to store such data

Comment: So can I for example do varchar(7000)?  What happens with my row width if I do three of these?

Comment: That doesn't answer the question as to what happens when the length of a row exceeds what can be stored on a single page.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - But off row storage will still be needed with three `varchar(7000)` columns if they are all full.

Comment: So if I need to store 7000 bytes is that okay with varchar(max)?  thanks

Comment: yeah you can use varchar(max).

Comment: @MartinSmith: does that mean `varchar(7000)` will be stored off-row as well? I thought that only happens with `varchar(max)` (hence my comment)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Yes, if the combined length of the row exceeds 8K then `varchar(x)` can be stored off row as row overflow data (with a pointer to it in the row itself)

Comment: @MartinSmith: thanks. I wasn't aware of that. Will a small value (eg. 100 chars) for a `varchar(max)` column be stored "inline" or "out-of-row"

Answer (score 2):

for a blob of text use varchar(max)

if you're storing XML use XML

There are BLOBs for binary data

These are often stored off-table (automatically) for various performance reasons.

So yet you can, but nevertheless, you might be doing something a bit wrong.  If you share what you're trying to do, we can be more specific.

Comment: So is a varchar(max) always stored off-table? If I want to store in table what is the maximum I can store?

Comment: Why does it matter?  A varchar(max) allows you to store 2gb.  The fact it's off table isn't necessarily relevant but if you explain why your so concerned about it I might be able to give a better answer